# Using bootstrap-modal as Backbone.js view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to create a Backbone.js view based on a Twitter bootstrap-modal, which makes use of Backbone's automatic event delegation via the `events` attribute of the view.

Unfortunately, bootstrap-modal seems to break Backbone's event delegation as it clones the view HTML before displaying the modal:

```
that.$element
      .appendTo(document.body)
      .show()
```

My view:

```
App.Views.ProjectsNav ||= {}

class App.Views.ProjectsNav.NewProjectView extends Backbone.View
  events: {
    'click .save': 'save',
    'shown':       'shown'
  }

  save: (e) ->
    ...
    false

  shown: () ->
    App.Helpers.Forms.setFocus($(@el), true)
    false

  render: () ->
    $(@el).html(ich.nav_edit_project_template(@model.toJSON()))
    @$('.modal').modal({'show': true, 'keyboard': true, 'backdrop': true})
    @
```

The corresponding (Mustache) HTML template:

```
<div class="modal hide" style="display: none; ">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <a href="#" class="close">×</a>
    <h3>New Project</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body form-stacked">
    <label for="name">Name</label> <input type="text" name="name" value="{{name}}"/><input type="hidden" name="lock_version" value="{{lock_version}}"/>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="save btn primary">Create</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="cancel btn secondary">Cancel</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Neither `save` nor `shown` are called when the respective events are triggered.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there an "opened" callback of some sort that you could use to fill the modal with HTML? Basically bypass the cloning (or at least the part of the cloning that is screwing up `delegate`).

Comment: Yes, cf. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap-modal.js. Unfortunately, the show event is called before the clone (and I am not getting the shown event due to the original problem).

Comment: What about the `shown` event? "This event is fired when the modal has been made visible to the user (will wait for css transitions to complete)."

Comment: Well, as the `shown` event is fired after the HTML fragment has been moved to another place in the DOM (`document.body`), the backbone view is not getting its callback invocation (`@el` is no longer pointing there).

Comment: Could you create the modal and then put the Backbone view inside it?

Comment: Ok, after some extended debugging as well as reading the bootstrap-modal source, I have a solution. Will document it tomorrow.

Comment: Waiting for a solution! I have the same problem in Sammy.js. I will put a bounty on it tomorrow, so if you could solve that too, that would be great:-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827136/modal-dialog-in-sammy-js

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Allright, so the solution is was rather simple:

```
App.Views.ProjectsNav ||= {}

class App.Views.ProjectsNav.NewProjectView extends Backbone.View
  tagName: 'div'

  events: {
    'click .save':   'save',
    'click .cancel': 'hide',
    'hidden':        'hidden',
    'shown':         'shown'
  }

  initialize: (options) ->
    super(options)
    @collection = options.collection

  hide: () ->
    @el.modal(true).hide()
    false

  save: (e) ->
    ...
    @model.save(attrs, {
      success: (project) =>
        @model = project
        @collection.add(@model)
        @hide()
      error: (project) =>
        alert('Something went wrong: ' + project)
      }
    )
    false

  render: () ->
    @el = ich.nav_edit_project_template(@model.toJSON()).modal('keyboard': true, 'backdrop': true)
    @delegateEvents()
    @el.modal('show': true)
    @

  hidden: () ->
    @remove()
    false

  shown: () ->
    App.Helpers.Forms.setFocus($(@el), true)
    false
```

Summing things up, the key is to split showing the modal into two steps giving the possibility to assign `@el` and invoke `@delegateEvents()` afterwards before making it visible. `@el.modal(true)` can be used to get access to the object controlling the modal, e.g., to programmatically hide it.

Comment: I had to add this.$el = $(this.el); before the @delegateEvents() row. delegateEvents seems to be using this.$el, instead of this.el and ithout this line it is probably referencing wrong elements.

Comment: I also had to use $("#myModal").modal("hide"); to hide the modal. With this.modal(true).hide() by background turns black and the actual dialog stays in place. I guess these differences could be due to differences in the templating engines. I'm using JsViews and adding the modal this way: this.el = $($.render["myTemplate"](this.model.toJSON())).modal({...});

Comment: Juha Palomäki: I guess you are using Bootstrap 2, which was still under development when I wrote the above answer and needs some changes. I'll extend my answer with my Bootstrap 2 approach...

Comment: just use view.setElement instead '@el = ...' and '@delegateEvents()'