# Backbone, Bootstrap modal within template not showing

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap, eco

I am trying to generate a modal for each of my posts so that each post has a modal containing the post content(and eventually comments). When the comment link is clicked the modal will appear. The thing is I have to create a bootstrap modal block for each post so i decided it would be easiest to do this in my backbone template. Why isn't this working?

Here is my code:

### app/assets/templates/posts/index.jst.eco

```
<% for post in @posts.models: %>
<tbody><td>
<%= post.get('content') %>
</td></tbody>
<tr><td>
<a href="#<%= post.get('id') %>">Comment</a>
</td></tr>
<div class="modal" id="post-<%= post.get('id')%>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-header">
<%= post.get('content') %>
</div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

### app/assets/javascripts/routers/posts_router.js.coffee

```
class Voice.Routers.Posts extends Backbone.Router
        routes:
                '': 'index'
                ':id': 'show'
        initialize: ->
                @collection = new Voice.Collections.Posts()
                @collection.fetch()
        index: ->
                view = new Voice.Views.PostsIndex(collection: @collection)
                $('#container').html(view.render().el)
        show: (id) ->
                $("#post-#{id}").modal('show')
```

There are no errors in the js console, the modals just don't seem to appear.
each post has a modal block with an html id field equal to "post-(the posts id)"

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Check if it should be `$("#post-#{id}")` or `$("#post-{id}")` ?

Comment: yes I am sure, backbone is functioning correctly but my bootstrap modal is not functioning correctly. this is a question geared towards bootstrap modals functioning while within an eco template used by backbone view

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using bootstrap-modal as Backbone.js view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811735/using-bootstrap-modal-as-backbone-js-view)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds very similar to a lot of SO questions on Bootstrap modals and using Backbone. Checkout this solution from Dereck Bailey,

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/17/managing-a-modal-dialog-with-backbone-and-marionette/

```
// the template
<script id="modal-view-template" type="text/html">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h2>This is a modal!</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>With some content in it!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn">cancel</button>
    <button class="btn-default">Ok</button>
  </div>
</script>

// the html has only one modal div
<div id="modal"></div>


// inside your show router function
var view = new MyView();
view.render();

var $modalEl = $("#modal");

$modalEl.html(view.el);
$modalEl.modal();
```

His explanation is,

> The core of the problem that people run in to when using a modal
>   dialog is that the modal plugin removes the DOM element that wraps the
>   modal, from the DOM. It usually gets added to some special holding
>   location where the modal plugin can guarantee that the element won’t
>   be visible until the modal dialog is opened. I’m over-generalizing
>   this a bit, but many of the modal dialogs work this way or in a
>   similar manner.
>
> The problem that this usually causes is that a Backbone view will lose
>   it’s event handling when the DOM element gets moved around by the
>   modal dialog. When the modal dialog removes the view’s `el` from the
>   DOM, the `events` configuration is lost because the DOM element has
>   been moved or removed from the DOM and jQuery had to let go of the
>   events. When the `el` is re-added to the DOM for displaying it as a
>   modal, then, the `events` are not re-attached.