# how to get twitter bootstrap.modals play well with backbone?

Tags: backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

as subject, I've already read another question regarding the similar problem:
[modal-dialog-with-backbone-and-marionette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546560/backbone-bootstrap-modal-within-template-not-showing/13549250#13549250)

But I don't want to introduce `backbone.marionette` into my project.

I'm wondering if there's any other alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by placing and empty `div` as container for modal dialog into the bottom of my page:

```
    <!-- Charge -->
    <div id="charge_dialog_container" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

    </div>
```

defined the rest of the dialog in the template:

```
    <script id="charge_dialog_template" type="text/template">
        <div class="modal-header">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="icon-ok"></i> OK</button>
        </div>
    </script>
```

During the view construction in `initialize` function I did the `modal()` stuff:

```
        ChargeView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: $('#charge_dialog_container'),
            initialize: function() {
                this.render();
                this.$el.modal({'backdrop': 'static'});
            },
            render: function() {
                var template = _.template($('#charge_dialog_template').html());
                this.$el.html(template);
            }
        });
```

Comment: looks a nice approach, will try later and give feedback afterwards, thanks ;)

Comment: awesome, applied and event bindings work like a charm, really nice ;)

Comment: I had to unbind when closing the dialog (cancel, save etc) otherwise I found events were fired N times (where N was the number of times the dialog had been opened) for old modal dialogs - $(@el).unbind() did it.

Comment: or probably `$el.remove()`, event tends to be polluted with in-appropriate bindings.